# Are this foreign key instances the same?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, foreign-keys

Is there any difference in declaring foreign keys on tables between this two options?

**OPTION 1**

```
create table Table1 (

    name varchar(255),
    id_fkey int references Table2 (id)
);
```

**OPTION 2**

```
create table Table1 (

    name varchar(255),
    id_fkey int,
    foreign key (id_fkey) references Table2 (id)
);
```

Are both declarations of a proper `foreign key` or do they have any difference?

Comment: They are the same. (But I'd specify constraint name too, e.g. `constraint fk_table2 foreign key (id_fkey) references Table2 (id)`.)

Comment: FYI: MySQL does not support foreign keys declared as column constraints. You will not get an error, but MySQL will not save the constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are two ways to do the same thing. The first syntax is called *column constraint*, the second *table constraint*.

The only real difference is that a foreign key over more than one column can only be written as a table constraint.